# Mule 4 Project Anypoint - import external Jar with Flows and Java

Tags: import, mulesoft

I am using latest Studio and embedded 4.1.5 engine.
I created a CommonProject with some reusable flows.
1 of the flow is using DW2.0 and is using a local class to cast the result of the transformation. CommonProject and DW work on its own.

Then I created a second project CallerProject. Added CommonProject as a dependency, and added the CommonProject FLOW via IMPORT:

When I call the CallerProject FLOW that uses the CommonProject imported flow, all seems to be working up to the DW2.0 transformation that is failing since the CLASS is not found.

Error: "Unable to find class ..."

Anything obvious I missed?
The java class is in the CommonProject JAR within the CallerProject JAR

Comment: i tried this out. a project importing another common project via maven. the common project has a local java class and the caller project uses that java class in dw. it works for me. is there any other info you can share? can you share the exact error msg?

Comment: Hi Ryan actually found the reason. I in fact also did your test and  it was working for me too. The only difference in my real project was that the caller was having few classes within the same package as the class referenced in the DW of the common project. Just by moving the caller project java package into different one (not the same as the package of the common) it worked

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Mule in the new class loading mechanism and I will be informing them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to import a project JAR file. The steps for that is:- File-> import -> Anypoint Studio -> Packaged Mule application(.jar).

Comment: Hi mate, not what I want, I am building a reusable Mule FLOW and therefore I want to use this in many Mule projects. I understand the best approach in CH Mule is to have it added as a Maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention mavenizing your flow.
This should help:

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-add-a-call-to-an-external-flow-in-Mule-4

Comment: This is exactly what I did!!!
The problem is that the Common Flows who is using a JAVA class within a DW transformation, is giving throwing a CLASS NOT FOUND Exception when called from the External flows, while it is working if called as a normal Mule APP. 
Are there any specific things needed for this scenario (DW, Java Class as part of a mul plugin)?

Comment: I remember coming across it as "known issues". If you are trying to access flows in the jar through flow reference, it wont be recognized. But while running, it will work as expected.

Comment: Please be sure to use the last version of the KB article.